# The network tab showing status of CSS file cancelled

Tags: javascript, node.js

The network tab showing status of `home.css` file cancelled.

There are other CSS in public folder `register.css` and `login.css` and they are working okay. 
This is the link I am using in `home.ejs`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" />
```

I am serving my static file using,

```
router.use(express.static("public"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you explain the error that is shown? It may be that you are not linking correctly to the file. Try adding `type="text/css` to the link's attributes

Comment: the status is showing cancelled and not serving to browser while other css are serving there is no other error